# MySQL: varchar or nvarchar in utf8mb4?

Tags: mysql

As this doc(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-national.html) said, these data type declarations are equivalent in MySQL:

```sql
CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8
NATIONAL CHARACTER(10)
NCHAR(10)
```

Does manually specifying a charset blur the difference between char and nchar in key functionalities (such as saving Unicode characters)?

In other words, what is the difference between `CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8` and `NCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8`?

Can this be understood to mean that, as long as the MySQL character set is already set to `utf8mb4`, then using either national or non-national column types will be equivalent (or at least not matter)?

Comment: You linked in the mysql manual page that contains the answers to your questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is literally no difference.

In fact, there's no real data type NCHAR or NVARCHAR in MySQL. These are just aliases for CHAR or VARCHAR with a system-defined character set.

Demo:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (
 col1 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8,
 col2 NATIONAL CHARACTER(10),
 col3 NCHAR(10)
);

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE test\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `col1` char(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` char(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` char(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

See how MySQL substituted the CHAR type as the table was created?

As a side issue, since MySQL 8.0 has deprecated utf8mb3, NCHAR and NVARCHAR should be changed to use utf8mb4 instead. This change was requested in 2015 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76529